# Sitecore Default Bucket Query For Multiple Templates

Tags: sitecore-query, buckets

I need to build a sitecore default bucket query for a bucketable folder which will display the articles which are based on different page templates. I was not able to find a specific syntax which we need to use the build the query, currently, it is only taking a single template to display the results.

The query which I am using currently is :

[image: Current Default Bucket Query]

But I need to display the results of the articles which are based on different templates :

[image: List of Templates]

Can anyone pls help me out !!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Build a Search Query dialog box, in the Search field, build your search query by adding the relevant filters, in your case, use the `template` filter and enter all the templates name (intellisense will automatically append template ID) you want to have your items based on. Query should look like this:

```
template:{B1C01A36-40F9-4D9B-8319-260767B760BC};template:{141F54F0-9C89-4193-B0F8-C9CB96A51913};sort:__updated;+location:{302969A3-C03A-48E8-BE4F-1BD6C3E32F0D}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Raman. It worked.

Comment: @AnvayJoshi Thanks for confirming and welcome to SSE :) Feel free to accept this answer and upvote if it worked for you.

Comment: Sure Raman. Will do. Thanks.